# A Challenge on linear functional and bounding property

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I took a midterm exam and after that wrote this problem down.  My instructor was unable to solve it.

The problem is copied here in order for anyone to help me.

> Suppose $f:E\to \mathbb{C}$ is a linear functional such that $\exists M \gt 0$ with the following property:
>
> $$ \forall x \in E \;\; |f(x)| \le M||x|| $$
>
> Show that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Recall that in this case "bounded" means "continuous".

Comment: Your post would be easier to read if you used MathJax/LaTex formatting. A [homegrown tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will get you started. A [quick overview](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, in this case would you please change it for me?

Comment: Ah okay, that's what I get for not reading "function-AL." My bad.

Comment: The property in the question is exactly the definition of boundedness. So you have to show that $f$ is bounded if it is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A bounded linear functional is just a special case of [bounded linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator), one for which the codomain is the field of scalars.  A linear mapping $f:E\to V$ between normed vector spaces is a *bounded linear operator* iff:

$$ \exists M \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in E \;\; ||f(x)||_V \le M||x||_E $$

The property given by this Question is then the very definition of a bounded linear operator, at least if we are assuming $f$ is a complex linear functional and complex vector space $E$ has the indicated norm $||\cdot ||$.

To prove that a bounded linear operator is *continuous* as a mapping of topological vector spaces, we need to show that for any open set $\mathscr{O}$ containing $f(x)$, there exists an open set $\mathscr{U}$ containing $x$ s.t. $f(\mathscr{U}) \subseteq \mathscr{O}$.

By the linearity of $f$ it suffices to carry out the argument for an open neighborhood of $f(0)=0$ in $V$, first translating $\mathscr{O}$ to an open neighborhood of the origin $\mathscr{O} - \{f(x)\}$ in $V$, and finally translating the open neighborhood of the origin in $E$ to an open set containing $x$ by adding $x$.

For normed vectors spaces $E,V$ this is precisely what the inequality involving positive (real) constant $M$ allows us to show.  Namely if $\mathscr{O}$ is a open set containing the origin in $V$, then there must be an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that the $\epsilon$-ball around the origin is contained in $\mathscr{O}$:

$$ \forall y \in V \; (\; ||y||_V \lt \epsilon \implies y \in \mathscr{O} \;) $$

Setting $\delta = \epsilon/M$ we define $\mathscr{U}$ to be the $\delta$-ball around the origin in $E$:

$$ \mathscr{U} = \{ x \in E : ||x||_E \lt \delta \} $$

Now if $x \in \mathscr{U}$, we have by the inequality involving $M$:

$$ ||f(x)||_V \le M ||x||_E \lt M \cdot \delta \le \epsilon $$

Thus $f(\mathscr{U}) \subseteq \mathscr{O} $, as required to prove continuity.

Comment: Dear @Hardmath, i need more detail :)

Comment: @MichleJordan: Please have at least a quick look at the link I gave to defining "bounded linear operator".  Were you given a different definition?  Did I misinterpret what you mean by "linear functional" $f:E\to \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: i can say, i dont know...

Comment: @hardmath Presumably, "bounded" means "continuous" in the topological sense.

Comment: @DavidMitra: I've added a sketch of the proof that a bounded linear operator is continuous as a topological map, but I suspect this distinction will be difficult for the original poster to evaluate.