# Vector space of complex sequences of the form $a_{2n}=n²a_{2n-1}$ for $n=1,2,...$ is closed (making use of the $l_{\infty}$ norm)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to show that the subspace, say $A$, of $c_0$ (which I use to denote the space of all complex sequences converging to $0$, equipped with the $l_{\infty}$ norm) which contains the sequences of the form $(a_n)$ with $a_{2n}=n^2a_{2n-1}$ for $n=1,2,...$ is closed.

I think I picture the reason why by taking a sequence of elements of $A$ and working by contradiction, but I can't get a proper proof.

After quite some work done with $\epsilon$'s all around, I get nothing neat... Could you help me by explaining how you would write this down?

Comment: How many of the sequences of this form converge to zero?

Comment: Aren't there infinitely many? With the restriction maybe that they must have a tail of zeros? I'm not sure about what I'm saying or where I'm going here...

Comment: @hardmath - note that this is not a recursive formula. it just says that the even values are determined from the odd values. But the odd values are are free to be anything.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: The odd index entries must of course converge to zero, but since the even index entries must also converge to zero, the condition on the odd index entries is more stringent (by virtue of "the even values ... determined from" them).

Comment: @hardmath - Perhaps I should have said that the even entries are free to be anything (provided of course that they converge to $0$), and the odd entries are derived from them. In any case, the point is: Kika is correct, this is not a trivial subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a mapping $f:c_0 \to c_0$ by $f(\{a_i\}_{i=1}^\infty) = \{k^{-2} a_{2k} - a_{2k-1}\}_{k=1}^\infty$.

This map is bounded and linear, so continuous.

The kernel of $f$ is $A = \{ \{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \mid a_{2k} = k^2 a_{2k-1} \}$.

Therefore $A$, as the pre-image of a closed set $\{0\}$, is closed.

Comment: What does the second line rely on? I'm not sure I have seen that before...

Comment: @Kika: If you are studying normed vector spaces (such as $c_0$ with the $\ell_\infty$ norm), it is a good exercise to show [bounded linear mappings are continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041306/a-challenge-on-linear-functional-and-bounding-property/1041354#1041354).  Or are you asking about showing this particular map is bounded or linear?

Comment: No, you have definitely answered my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would show this is closed by showing that the complement is open. Note that $\mathbf a =\{a_n\} \notin A$ if there is at least one index $k$ such that $a_{2k} \ne k^2a_{2k-1}$. Since you are using the $l_\infty$ norm, any $\mathbf b$ with $\|\mathbf{b - a}\| < \epsilon$ must have in particular that $|b_{2k} - a_{2k}| < \epsilon$ and $b_{2k-1} - a_{2k-1}| < \epsilon$. Given that $k$ is a fixed value (for a given $\mathbf a$), it should not be too hard to find an $\epsilon$ that prevents $\mathbf b$ from satisfying the condition for $k$ either.